# Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'HelloAndroid'. sun/security/x509/X500Name

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just installed Eclipse-Classic 3.7.2 and android SDK. Also installed/configured eclipse with ADT plugin.

Now after following the steps in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html to create a "Hello World" application I tried to run the application in Android Emulator. But this is throwing an error

> Errors occurred during the build.   Errors running builder 'Android
>   Package Builder' on project 'HelloAndroid'. 
>   sun/security/x509/X500Name

Can you please explain me what am I doing wrong here, or what do I need to fix for this error.

Thank you
Zeeshan

Comment: Obtained same problem -> because of running IBM JRE on computer. Problem solved specifying Oracle JRE path in eclipse.ini by "-vm <path>" arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related with the JVM you are working with, but also the certificate that have to be generated with the keytool from this JVM.

Here you are the commands i have used to solve this problem in my Linux Ubuntu v11.04 system:

1. I have installed the Oracle/Sun SDK 1.6 ( SDK not the JRE one ) on my computer.
2. I made this new SUN JVM the default with the following instruction

   sudo update-alternatives --config java

   **Note** A list is shown with all the available JVM on your system, select the SUN one.
3. Now you will be able to execute this command with the JVM provided by SUN:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
   ```

**Note** You should delete the old debug.keystore file before you execute this command, or rename it as you wish.

Now that your system is up and running, then you need to configure your new JVM in Eclipse in order to compile with this new version.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the ADT plugin was trying to use keytool utility present in JVM which launched eclipse. Which was IBM JDK, this failed as keytool which comes with IBM JDK is incompatible with the Sun version -- it has its a syntax that doesn't match the Google documentation, and it automatically creates the keystore file in ~/.keystore (without actually telling you where it was created).


**Below solution worked** for me:

1. Install sun jvm

2. From terminal execute: eclipse -vm path_to_sun_java/javaw

Instead of step 2, you can edit eclipse.ini to tell which jvm to use (ref [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini))

```
-vm
/usr/lib/sunjdk/bin/javaw
```