# Eclipse - Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder'

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I updated ADT from 22.x to the latest 23.x and now I'm getting the following error when trying to run the project:

`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'Sample-project-1'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput`

Here's the error in the log:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
>     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:212)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
>     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
>     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
>     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
>     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
>     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
>     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput cannot be found by com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_23.0.2.1259578
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     ... 17 more

Of course this is all gibberish to me.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: check this link hope it helps you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684318/errors-running-builder-android-package-builder-on-project-helloandroid-sun

Comment: I've already read that, I don't understand how any of the answers apply to me. It's all about Linux and key tools and what not, don't know what that is, my Eclipse was working perfectly before I updated an hour ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has just happened to be because i have manually updated the ADT plugin.

I had to do a manual update of ADT plugin since eclipse refused to find an update via "Check for updates". After the manual update I started getting "package builder" errors.

What worked for me was to remove all the ADT related plugins such as..

```
DDMS
ADT
ANdroid Hierarchy Viewer
Android Native Development Tools
Android Traceview
Tracer for OpenGL ES
```

then, do a fresh ADT install and am good to go.

Hope that helps and is related to your problem.

Comment: Perfect!! I spent hours to try to fix this. I had the problem with the update of ADT through Eclipse. The stupid eclipse didn't remove the old stuff. So you have to **manually erase the old packages before installing the new**. How stupid to call that an update! Anyway... thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Glad that helped. I totally understand that feeling about "UPDATE"

Answer (score 0):

do u have this annotations.jar after update `android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar` in your updated folder

if not try this ,

```
..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\annotations\android-support-annotations.jar
```

and copy it to `..\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar`

and then try to run your Project, Hope that will solve your problem

Comment: This had no effect. The same error is being reported.